# How come my link is overlooked?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, button, interface-design

I'm fairly new to designing. As of now, I have this design:

[image: webpage design]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

As you can see there is a small link in the upper right corner (*Upload Prenda Link*). When clicked, it toggles the an uploading `div` to look like this:

[image: website design]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

and vice versa..

The link itself looks like the user will not be able to see it immediately or he/she may overlook it while using the web page.

How can I call attention to this link so it will not be overlooked?

Comment: According to a study I can't source at the moment, using orange for links/buttons has the greatest effect for encouraging people to click on them. It may help you and I think a single/few orange elements wouldn't look out of place in your design. I would make it a button rather than a text only link because it's very easy to miss. Ryan's tips about proximity are also highly relevant here.

Comment: The simple answer is: people see and recognise a form to fill in, work through the form from top to bottom focusing on the form, and never look anywhere else on the page because forms normally go from top to bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your link is proximity and emphasis.

If you want people to notice it you need to add design to the entire page such as background colors to direct the user to different parts. That is a starting point for adding **emphasis** to the Upload Prenda.

Depending on what you do with backgrounds, graphics, and the design you may also need to adjust the **Proximity**. This means to move the element closer to the rest of the content, so a user can understand they are related. If you look at [Gestalt Proximity](http://www.andyrutledge.com/gestalt-principles-3.php) you'll see the orange dots in different grouping patterns and proximity to each other. In your current design it is as if you have a group of dots at the top of the page, another group in the middle, and then a lone dot "Upload Prenda" off on the side. It needs to be grouped either visually, spatially, or both with the rest of the content.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is the answer in its most basic form (a good thing). The link itself is so far off to the side that it is either ignored (lacks emphasis) or, **more likely**, discounted as not relevant to the form itself (not proximate).

Comment: And further - since the link is on the right side of the page, it will more often be overlooked due to the F-shape (http://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/) that user's eyes follow when scanning the page.

Comment: Hey Great thanks to this i was asking for a General Solution i really do no know why does it posted as off topic. -_-

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way in my opinion is simple - underline the link!

Since older days when links were invented, they were all underlined and easy to recognise. Underlining was the simplest, most obvious, unambiguous way of displaying links.

Then this new trend came in and, for some reason, sites started removing the underlines. Maybe because they were perceived "boring", "old-fashioned", "ugly", whatever. Unfortunately, the result is the constant confusion battling the user to guess whether this or that is still a link or not. And then, even worse, underlining became used for other purposes than links. To  have the confusion reach its perfection :)

So my advice is simple:

- If the purpose of your site is to impress the user with unique beauty and style, e.g. if you are web designer looking for job, by all means use your creativity and originality.
- If, on the other hand, your site's purpose is practical and functional, and, most important, is meant to be simple to use, please put the UX and usability before the beauty, and underline your links. And don't underline anything else.

Sites like amazon or ebay are not beautiful but they work.

Comment: nice answer sir :)

Comment: Nice solid points but I believe that "put the UX and usability before the beauty" should be a standard for _all_ websites that I actually want to navigate around on.

Comment: @SaturnsEye Indeed :)